# Probability of two out of three randomly chosen numbers in $[1, 20]$ being $1$ and $2$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm getting a close, but not correct answer to this problem:

Three random numbers are chosen in the interval $[1,20]$, with each number having the same odds of being picked. What is the probability of at least two of these numbers being $1$ and $2$?

My reasoning: $20^3 = 8000$ is all the possible combination of three numbers in that interval. For the odds of two being $1$ or $2$, we can multiply the number of permutation of three digits by $20$, which is the number of possibilities for the third number to be picked: $3!\cdot20 = 120$.

Thus, my answer would be $\frac{120}{8000} = 0.015$. However, the correct answer is $\frac{3}{190}$ which is about $0.0158$.

What am I missing?

Comment: Looking at the denominator $190$, it seems that the question expected the numbers chosen to be distinct.

Comment: Makes sense. I was confused because this wasn't specified, but the result $\frac{6\cdot18}{20\cdot19\cdot18}$ is correct so I guess that clears out the doubts...